# Restart service in Linux when a process reaches certain memory size

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, heap-memory

I'm aware that this is not a good solution, but we have a problem with a 3rd party product that runs on tomcat and often throws Heap Space error. I would like to know if there is a way to monitor the memory consumed by certain process (not using PID but process name) and if it exceeds a limit, then restart tomcat service.

I have tried assigning more memory to it, but this only slows down the process.

Thanks

Comment: If it OOM's with some regularit, you could consider restarting it every T-x timeunit, using eg. `cron`.

Comment: We tried that, but there's no pattern, hundreds of users are there and connect randomly within a range of 8 hours.

Comment: You could run the Tomcat instance through the [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp). It can detect OOM exceptions and automatically restarts the wrapped service.

Comment: We ended up increasing resources on the server and restart Tomcat daily. But I do wanna find a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering that `ps` is inherently unprecise when it comes to actually *used* memory (it shows *allocated* memory) you could probably get a "good enough" measure using a combination of `ps` and `jps`:

```
ps u -p `jps -v | grep "<yourname>" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

I'm assuming that by "process name" you mean something that will identify the specific `java` instance.

This will give something like

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      6816  0.6  7.1 1454376 281436 pts/2  Sl+  Feb03 102:20 /usr/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -jar /opt/minecraft/minecraft_serv
```

where the `VSZ` (or Virtual Size) is the number you need.

Cheers,